# If $ a, b, c$ are real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, then show $ab+bc+ca> \frac{-1}{2}$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, sums-of-squares

> If $ a, b, c$ are real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, then show that  $ab+bc+ca\ge \frac{-1}{2}$

If figured out that if I put $(a+b+c)^2 = 0$ then I will get the above answer, but $(a+b+c)^2 = 0$ is not given in the question, so is there any other method to do it, or the question is wrong?

Comment: The question is fine, and the method is fine, too, but you should be a little more careful: start with $(a+b+c)^2\ge 0$.

Comment: When $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},b=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},c=0$, we get $ab+bc+ca\color{red}=-\frac 12$.

Comment: Yes equality sign is Missing in the answer, I will correct it.

Comment: $$\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2}\leq (ab+bc+ca)\leq 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use $0\le(a+b+c)^2=1+2(ab+bc+ca)$. Your inequality actually shouldn't be strict, because e.g. we can take $a=0,\,b=-c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ to get $a+b+c=0,\,a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: I got it, I was missing $(a+b+c)^2 \ge 0$ in every real number case